# How to fill in the angular-material card header

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, material-ui

I have angular-material classic card like with the next template

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.</p>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image]

and trying to fill in silver header like

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `mat-card-header` and `mat-card-content`,

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
   <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
   </mat-card-header>
   <mat-card-content>
    <p>The Shiba Inu is the smallest of the six original and distinct spitz breeds of dog from Japan.</p>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

and set these css

```
mat-card-header{
  background: #12121212;
  padding: 5px;
  color:white;
}

mat-card-content{
  padding: 10px;
}

mat-card{
  padding:0;
}
```

[example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsnpbv)

Comment: i've upadted question with my card layout and can you update your unswear with `<mat-card-title>` nested in `<mat-card-header>`